# Configure not detecting python package

Tags: package-management

I am trying to install referencer. However upon running config, it displays the following message.

```
checking for python script directory... ${prefix}/lib/python3.6/site-packages
checking for python extension module directory... 
${exec_prefix}/lib/python3.6/site-packages
checking for headers required to compile python extensions...   File "string>", 
line 1
import sys; print sys.prefix
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
 File " string> ", line 1
    import sys; print sys.exec_prefix
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
not found
configure: WARNING: Python not found, disabling python support
```

I installed the python packages `python-all-dev` and `pygame` with `pip` and I have also installed `anaconda`, but the problem still persists. I tried just going on without download the required package, however the make file requires it.

Can somebody link me to the required package?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? 18.04 has python3 as the default - which may be an issue here

Comment: Yes 18.04. What should I do in this case?

Comment: Hmm... try `./configure PYTHON=/usr/bin/python2`

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Can you also explain what you did?

Comment: Please see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Beaver) [has python3 as the default python](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes#Other_base_system_changes_since_16.04_LTS).

Although you installed the python2-based `python-dev` header package, when the software's configure script actually invokes `python`, it results in the invocation of `python3` - which fails because of incompatible syntax:

```
checking for headers required to compile python extensions...   File "<string>", line 1
    import sys; print sys.prefix
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  File "<string>", line 1
    import sys; print sys.exec_prefix
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
not found
configure: WARNING: Python not found, disabling python support
```

You can override the default by setting the variable `PYTHON=/usr/bin/python2` on the command line:

```
$ ./configure PYTHON=/usr/bin/python2
.
.
.
checking for /usr/bin/python2 version... 2.7
checking for /usr/bin/python2 platform... linux2
checking for /usr/bin/python2 script directory... ${prefix}/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
checking for /usr/bin/python2 extension module directory... ${exec_prefix}/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
checking for headers required to compile python extensions... found
```

Comment: Ohh okay, but why doesn't the actual program requires python3?

Comment: @mathisbetter I don't know - maybe because it was apparently last updated in 2014?